# Why does a*ad$ match the string "ad"?

Tags: python, regex

Shouldn't the `a*` of the following regex match with the `a` in the string, which only leaves `d` so the `ad$` shouldn't match, right? Why is this true?

```
pattern = r"a*ad$"

print(re.search(pattern, "ad"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't the `a*` match with the `a` in the string?

No, because `*` means `a` can match *zero* or more times, so the `''` *empty string* also matches that expression. That leaves `'ad'` after the initial empty string to match for the remainder of the expression.

A regex will consider both options here (both `''`, the empty string, and `'a'` satisfy the `a*` pattern).

Use `a+` if you wanted the pattern to match *at least once*.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know it checks all options.

Comment: This is why there is such a thing as [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), where you can make a regex engine try out an exponential number of options.